# How to get a 4v4 chess board version using the python chess library

Tags: python, chess, python-chess

I am trying to figure out how to use the chess library in python to get a `4x4` board instead of an `8x8` with Rook, Queen, King, and Rook at the back and the middle rows being Pawns.

I tried setting up the board through this line but it gives an error saying that it expects `8` columns per row in position apart of fen

```py
board = chess.Board("rqkr/pppp1Qpp/2n2n2/4p3/2B1P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNB1K1NR b KQkq - 0 4")
```

I just would like to get a working `4x4` board instead of `8x8`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `python-chess` only works with 8x8 boards.  Now, your setup does have 8 rows, and it had 8 columns in every row but the first.  Were you trying to fake something here?

Comment: You could, I suppose, try "rqkr4/pppp4/PPPP4/RQKR4/8/8/8/8" and just play in the upper left corner.

Comment: Why is that interesting?  Aren't all the games the same?  If I start c3xb2+, black has take with the queen ...b1xb2, which I can then take a3xb2+, he has to take with his king ...c1xb2, I move the queen out b4-c3+ and he's screwed.

Comment: I do not think there is a possible way to do so with the python-chess library. You might have to make a new 4x4 board class with pure python.

Comment: Python chess only supports boards for [registered variants](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/variant.html#). See list.

Comment: And as per my knowledge none of the registered variants include a 4x4 board. Also since you passed the fen into a standard board class it threw an error since it expects the board to have 8 rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a possible way to do so with the python-chess library. You might have to make a new 4x4 board class with pure python.

Python chess only supports boards for [registered variants](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/variant.html#).

None of the registered variants include a 4x4 board.

Also since you passed the board fen into a standard board class it threw an error since it expects the board to have 8 rows and columns.